# Bica 5 open cluster

Tags: star-cluster

Someone referred to the open cluster Bica 5. Is that to do with E Bica? How would I get information about this cluster? I do not have many options. I have been just trying general searches using Google, and on Arxiv - and various forums. Any help would be appreciated.

Eduardo Bica - Tracing the Galactic spiral structure with embedded clusters. 2015. In that paper there is a table of about 20 clusters, but it is not clear whether any of these is Bica-5.

I am trying to help out someone who is studying in a war zone. Hence the odd nature of the question. I am trying to get some more information - but was hoping that this was a question to which the answer was obvious, if you had the right background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is the fifth cluster in the [catalogue by produced by Eduardo Bica et al](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2019AJ....157...12B/abstract).

You can see its listing in a [list of clusters](http://www.astrosen.unam.mx/%7Ermm/SPMO_UBVRI_Survey/catalog_Name.html). That notes it is also known as MWSC 1964 and you can find it in [Simbad](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=bica%205&NbIdent=1&Radius=2&Radius.unit=arcmin&submit=submit%20id). Its coordinates are (in RA-Dec) 11:41:36 -62:25:09.  So it is not one of the clusters listed in the paper, which all have a RA between 2:45 and 7:20

You can use Simbad to search for astronomical objects and find references to them in the literature.

Comment: Thank you. That is excellent. I know it's a bit early, but I will accept this answer, since it entirely answers the question.